# Populate a Pandas SparseDataFrame from a SciPy Sparse Coo Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, sparse-matrix

(This question relates to ["populate a Pandas SparseDataFrame from a SciPy Sparse Matrix"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818783/populate-a-pandas-sparsedataframe-from-a-scipy-sparse-matrix). I want to populate a SparseDataFrame from a scipy.sparse.**coo**_matrix (specifically) The mentioned question is for a different SciPy Sparse Matrix (**csr**)...
So here it goes...)

I noticed Pandas now has [support for Sparse Matrices and Arrays](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/sparse.html).  Currently, I create `DataFrame()`s like this:

```
return DataFrame(matrix.toarray(), columns=features, index=observations)
```

Is there a way to create a `SparseDataFrame()` with a `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix()` or `coo_matrix()`? Converting to dense format kills RAM badly...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html#interaction-with-scipy-sparse

> A convenience method SparseSeries.from_coo() is implemented for creating a SparseSeries from a scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.

Within `scipy.sparse` there are methods that convert the data forms to each other. `.tocoo`, `.tocsc`, etc.  So you can use which ever form is best for a particular operation.

For going the other way, I've answered

[Pandas sparse dataFrame to sparse matrix, without generating a dense matrix in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084942/pandas-sparse-dataframe-to-sparse-matrix-without-generating-a-dense-matrix-in-m)

Your linked answer from 2013 iterates by row - using `toarray` to make the row dense.  I haven't looked at what the pandas `from_coo` does.

A more recent SO question on pandas sparse

[non-NDFFrame object error using pandas.SparseSeries.from_coo() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970070/non-ndfframe-object-error-using-pandas-sparseseries-from-coo-function)

---

From https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/sparse/scipy_sparse.py

```
def _coo_to_sparse_series(A, dense_index=False):
    """ Convert a scipy.sparse.coo_matrix to a SparseSeries.
    Use the defaults given in the SparseSeries constructor. """
    s = Series(A.data, MultiIndex.from_arrays((A.row, A.col)))
    s = s.sort_index()
    s = s.to_sparse()  # TODO: specify kind?
    # ...
    return s
```

In effect it takes the same `data`, `i`, `j` used to build a `coo` matrix, makes a series, sorts it, and turns it into a sparse series.