# Scipy sparse matrix as DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm developing tooling based on pandas DataFrame objects. I would like to keep scipy sparse matrices around as column of a DataFrame without converting it row-wise to a list / numpy array of dtype('O').

The snippet below doesn't work as pandas treats the matrix as a scalar, and suggests to add an index. When providing a pd.RangeIndex over the row indices in the matrix, the matrix gets repeated for every row in the dataframe (as pandas thinks it is a scalar).

```
ma = scipy.sparse.rand(10, 100, 0.1, 'csr', dtype=np.float64)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(X=ma))
```

This does work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(X=list(ma)))
```

However, this cuts up the matrix row-wise into CSR matrices each of 1 row. Which I would then need to vstack everytime I'd want to work on the original matrix.

Any pointers? I tried wrapping the CSR matrix into a pd.Series object, pretending it has dtype('O'), but I run into a lot of assumptions on the underlying data being numpy arrays and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a sparse dataframe or dataseries feature.  It is still experimental.  I've answered a few SO questions about converting back and forth between that and `scipy` sparse matrices.

From the sidebar:

[Populate a Pandas SparseDataFrame from a SciPy Sparse Coo Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34181494/populate-a-pandas-sparsedataframe-from-a-scipy-sparse-coo-matrix)

Without such a specialized pandas structure I don't see how a sparse matrix could be added to a pandas frame.  The internal structure of a sparse matrix is too different.  For a start it is not a subclass of numpy array.

A `csr` matrix is an object with data contained in 3 arrays, `ma.data` and `ma.indices` are 1d arrays with one value for each non-zero element of the array.  `ma.indptr` has a value for each row of the matrix.

`list(ma)` is meaningless.  `ma.toarray()` produces a 2d array with the same data, and will all those zeros filled in as well.

Other sparse matrix formats store their data in other structures - 3 equal length arrays for `coo`, two lists of lists for `lil`, and a dictionary of `dok`.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj for the reply. I'm actually not interested in accessing the SciPy matrix column by column through Pandas, only row wise or the matrix as a whole. I understand the mismatch between ndarray and the sparse matrix types on a memory layout level. I was hoping there was a abstraction where both could fit in ...

`list(ma)` is not enterily meaningless, at least for a CSR matrix it creates CSR matrices of one row for each row in the original CSR matrix.

Comment: I don't see how a matrix (2d), dense or sparse, can be used as a column of a Dataframe.  I believe `pandas` will try to map the columns of a 2d array onto an equal number of columns.  Cells can also be object pointers, but not whole column.  But I know numpy and scipy better than I know pandas.

Comment: Thanks again. I understand. Would be a convenient place to store a CSR matrix of feature vectors where very row corresponds to e.g. a label in another column of the DataFrame and being able to access the underlying CSR matrix _without_ copying or stacking it back together. Can't have everything I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, this doesn't answer your question exactly, but if anyone is looking for a quick workaround, and doesn't mind storing the matrix inefficiently as dense, this can be done as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(X=ma.todense().tolist())
```